# PostgreSQL 8.4 Column Update with aggregate function

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, sql-update

I have two tables, "Hello" and "World":

- "Hello" has two columns id(int) and id1(int, default value 0)
- "World" has column id2(int)

Whenever id = id2 I would like to +1 to id1.

I tried this using UPDATE like so

```
UPDATE "Hello" z1 set id1=z1.id1 + 1 FROM "World" z2 WHERE
z1.id = z2.id2
```

But that changed every column to 1 instead of adding 1 for every occurance of id=id2
After looking around for a solution it seems I need to use an aggregate function but 
from previous posts I know that isn't allowed within UPDATE.

I have a vague idea of one solution where I get the sum for id=id2 per id then put it in a temporary table and then UPDATE based on that value but I can't seem to put it together so I'm thinking that might not be the best path to a solution?

Comment: I don't think you need aggregates. How do you know that all of the id's were not zero before the query?. Your query looks like it should it work to me. Maybe a column is mixed up or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did:

**Initialization**

```
create table t1 (id int, n int default 0);
create table t2 (id int);

insert into t1 values (1), (2), (3);
insert into t2 values (1), (2), (2), (3), (3), (3);
```

**Tables at the beginning**

t1:

```
id ; n
1  ; 0
2  ; 0 
3  ; 0
```

t2

```
id
1
2
2
3
3
3
```

**Test case 1:**

```
update t1 z1 set n = z1.n + 1 from t2 z2 where z1.id = z2.id;
```

Result is what you described i.e. t1

```
id ; n
1  ; 1
2  ; 1 
3  ; 1
```

I suspect the reason for this result is that in `z1.n + 1` the value of `z1.n` is determined only at the beginning and it is not updated as more rows match. This way the result is equivalent to the one you get by executing a `SELECT` `select *, t1.n + 1 from t1,t2 where t1.id = t2.id;`

Please note that every `UPDATE` will increment all values in n by one if there are at least one row for which `t1.id = t2.id` is true.

**Test case 2:**

```
update t1 set n = (select count(*) from t2 where t2.id = t1.id)
```

Result was what you expected i.e. t1

```
id ; n
1  ; 1
2  ; 2 
3  ; 3
```

Please note that the end result is same after each `UPDATE` if the table `t2` has not been modified.